# In tikz double arrow head, increase the size of only one head

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have diagrams with arcs with heads produced with `\draw[<__|-, ...]` or `\draw[<<__|-, ...]`, like in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning]
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(A){A}; \node(B)[right=2cm of A]{B};
    \draw[<<__|-|__>, very thick] (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to increase only the length of the vertical bar? How it can be done? The ideal would be to define a style to apply to all the cases in my diagrams.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `arrows.meta` you can control all aspects of these arrows. I added two bars of different lengths (or widths) to the example.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning,arrows.meta]
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(A){A}; \node(B)[right=2cm of A]{B};
    \draw[{<<__Bar[width=1.5ex]}-{Bar[width=2ex]__>}, very thick] (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say that you can also manipulate the other arrows in similar ways.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.